# wget parse and insert mysql

Tags: mysql, curl, wget

Im using wget to get file. It has plain text, which I would like to insert to mysql database on appropriate columns.

Im completely loss of which approach, I should use.
I have been looking for curl, regex etc, but cant find a way.

Sample listed below:

Item1: one
Item2: two
Item3: lots of text on this line
and keeps going over for next line
Item4: four

Item1: five
Item2: six
Item3: lots of text on this line
and keeps going over for next line
Item4: eight

So how do I parse all data, and insert it to mysql. Above is just 2 samples, but page has about 50 (I did not want to list all 50 LOL)
Page does have some basic html stuff at the beginning and also at the end, and not sure, if I need to remove those, before inserting to database.

Thanks for all feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If data is not consistent, there is no one simple method I know of.

1. You can store the data in one column and then using SQL functions you can parse the data using regEx or split.

Second option will be try JSON insert, this NOSQL method will be handy if data is doesn't fit relational model.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-insert